# Creating a Python package for C++ code wrapped with pybind11 using setuptools

Tags: python, c++, setuptools, pybind11

I have a C++ file called `VBB.cpp` which contains implementations of a few classes and I wrote Python bindings for those classes using the `pybind11` library, these are located in `bindings.cpp`. I can successfully compile the code with:

```
g++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` bindings.cpp VBB.cpp -o VBB`python3-config --extension-suffix
```

And then use the C++ code from Python with `import library`.

I want to turn this into a Python package via `setuptools`. I just used the example `setup.py` file available at https://github.com/pybind/python_example and modified the `Extension` call with

```
Extension(
        'VBB',
        ['src/bindings.cpp', 'src/VBB.cpp'],
        include_dirs=[
            # Path to pybind11 headers
            get_pybind_include(),
            get_pybind_include(user=True)
        ],
        language='c++'
    ),
```

If I run the install script it compiles but if I try to run `import VBB` in Python, I get the following error:

`ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_VBB)`

I'm new to using `setuptools` so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong. The example package from GitHub works without any issues.

Comment: That error usually means the python and c++ sides have different names for the c++ extension. The names at both sides should be both `VBB`. This means using `PYBIND11_MODULE(VBB, m)` at the c++ side.

Comment: @Rzu Yes! That solved the problem. Thank you!